# No se puede invocar un objeto que posiblemente sea 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, typescript, reactjs

Trabajando en React, tengo un componente al que le pasaba un método como prop, y que se llamaba cuando el usuario ejecutaba una acción. El código es el siguiente:

> Nota: este código es simplificado de un fichero mucho más grande, es sólo para ilustrar el problema y puede contener errores causados al transcribir/modificar el código que no aparecen en el código completo que compila y funciona correctamente.

```
import React from 'react'

export default({
  nombres,
  cambioNombre,
}: {
  nombres: string[]
  cambioNombre: (args: { id: string; nombre: string }) => void
}) => (
    <div>
      {nombres.map(nombre => {
        const id = calculaId(nombre)
        const propsCompartidas = {
          key: id,
          onCambioNombre: (nuevoNombre: string) => cambioNombre(id, nuevoNombre)
        }
        return <OtroComponente {...propsCompartidas} />
      })}
    </div>
)
```

Ahora tengo que hacer que la función `cambioNombre` sea opcional, para ello simplemente añado un interrogante (`?`) detrás del nombre en la definición, tal que así:

```
cambioNombre?: (args: { id: string; nombre: string }) => void
```

Pero entonces el IDE me marca este error en la línea más abajo:

```
onCambioNombre: (nuevoNombre: string) => cambioNombre(id, nuevoNombre)
```

subrayando en rojo la llamada `cambioNombre` y mostrando el mensaje:

> Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'

Lo cual tiene sentido porque ahora `cambioNombre` puede que no se esté pasando como prop y sea `undefined` y el código falla al compilar... ¿Cómo puedo solucionar ese problema?

Comment: Perdón por mencionar una tonteria, pero por lo general se recomienda exportar componentes con nombre para que sea más fácil el poder debuguearlos. Te dejo [el tweet de Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/1093901838179618816) que lo menciona :D

Comment: @KacosPro No es una tontería y gracias por la recomendación y el enlace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes inspeccionar si la funcion es undefined. Al ser undefined, no invocas la funcion. Al no ser undefined, no invocas la funcion.

El codigo se veria un poco asi:

```js
(nuevoNombre: string) => {
  if (cambioNombre !== undefined) { 
    return cambioNombre(id, nuevoNombre);
  }
}
```

Otra manera de escribir lo mismo y mantenerlo inline seria:

```js
(nuevoNombre: string) => cambioNombre && cambioNombre(id, nuevoNombre)
```